# Shouldn't ROUGE-1 precision be equal to BLEU with w=(1, 0, 0, 0) when brevity penalty is 1?

Tags: natural-language, model-evaluation, validation, rouge, bleu

I am trying to evaluate a NLP model using BLEU and ROUGE. However, I am a bit confused about the difference between those scores. While I am aware that ROUGE is aimed at recall whilst BLEU measures precision, all ROUGE implementations I have come across also output precision and the F-score. The original ROUGE paper only briefly mentions precision and the F-score, therefore I am a bit unsure about what meaning they have to ROUGE. Is ROUGE mainly about recall and the precision and F-score are just added as a compliment, or is the ROUGE considered to be the combination of those three scores?

What confuses me even more is that to my understanding ROUGE-1 precision should be equal to BLEU when using the weights (1, 0, 0, 0), but that does not seem to be the case.
The only explanation I could have for this is the brevity penalty. However, I checked that the accumulated lengths of the references are shorter than the length of the hypothesis, which means that the brevity penalty is 1.
Nonetheless, BLEU with w = (1, 0, 0, 0) scores 0.55673 while ROUGE-1 precision scores 0.7249.

What am I getting wrong?

I am using [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/translate/bleu_score.html) to evaluate BLEU and [rouge-metric](https://github.com/li-plus/rouge-metric) for ROUGE.

**Disclaimer**: I already posted this question on [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/86981/shouldnt-rouge-1-precision-be-equal-to-bleu-with-w-1-0-0-0-when-brevity-pe), however after not receiving any replies and doing some additional research on the differences between Data Science and Cross Validated, I figured that this question might be better suited for Cross Validated (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: What data are you using to calculate BLEU and ROGUE-1? Your calculations may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

BLEU computes a similarity score based on 1) n-gram precision(usually for 1, 2, 3, and 4-grams); 2) a penalty for too-short system translations.

$$\text{BLEU}=\text{BP}*\exp(\sum_{n=1}^N w_n \log p_n)$$
where $p_n$ is the modified precision for n-gram, the base of log is the natural base $e$, $w_n$ is weight between 0 and 1 for $\log p_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N w_n =1$, and BP is the brevity penalty to penalize short machine translations.

\begin{equation}
\text{BP} = 
    \begin{cases} 
    1 & \text{if $c>r$}\\
    \exp(1-\frac{r}{c}) & \text{if $c\le r$}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

Plug in $w = (1, 0, 0, 0)$ and $\text{BP} = 1$, we obtain this: $\text{BLEU}=p_1$ which is the precision of the uni-gram overlap.

I thought in your case the BP might be not 1. The penalty is not one if $r$, the effective reference length which is the length of the reference that’s closest to the hypothesis, is greater than the length of the candidate sentence. I don't know how you calculated `the accumulated lengths of the references` to get the brevity penalty 1.

> Is ROUGE mainly about recall and the precision and F-score are just added as a compliment, or is the ROUGE considered to be the combination of those three scores?

ROUGE is based on recall but sometimes $F_1$ version (combination of precision and recall) of it is reported anyway. Please refer to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/311128/103153).

References:

1. [Bilingual Evaluation Understudy (BLEU)](https://leimao.github.io/blog/BLEU-Score/)
2. [BLEU: a Method for Automatic Evaluation of Machine Translation](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P02-1040.pdf)
3. [What is ROUGE and how it works for evaluation of summarization tasks?](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/vip/teach/DMcourse/5_topicmodel_summ/notes_slides/What-is-ROUGE.pdf)
4. [Lecture 15: Natural language generation](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/slides/cs224n-2019-lecture15-nlg.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. However, as stated in my initial post, I made sure that the brevity penalty is 1 in my case. So it is not the cause for the differences in precision scores.
By now I have a theory based on a discussion I had over on the datascience exchange: BLEU uses a micro-average while the ROUGE implementation I use employs a macro-average. However, I am still uncertain whether this is an error in that ROUGE implementation or if that's correct. From reading the ROUGE paper I would've guessed it's micro-averaged as well, but a few implementations I found use a macro-average.